# page using JS to display info - need to extract that info

Tags: javascript, html, feed, text-extraction, html-content-extraction

I need to turn the results of the leaderboard here secondsync.com/leaderboard.html#Wed-May-22-2013/totals into a feed.

They use a js to pull this info. How do I indentify the JS and pull the data from another page?

Thanks.

Comment: what is "a js"? you can view the javascript used by a page by viewing the page source.

Comment: can't find the js unfortunately

Comment: it's right near the top of the page. anywhere there's a `<script>` tag, there's javascript inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use this tutorial 
 http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/php-crawler-tutorial/   (requires some PHP and REGEX skills)
to crawl the content of the page then use REGEX to access the content you need.

With regex you could match() the first:

```
<td class="tweets">*<td>
```

you should get something like

```
<td class="tweets">91,621<td>
```

Then replace() every <*> with ''

and the number 91,621 remains.

This could be modified to <'td class="peak">* ,
if you are interested in the peak or something similar, just look up how they (secondsync) describe it in their source code.

Sorry for not helping better, I can´t think of a better solution right now.

Comment: Please let me know if my solution worked out for you, if your project, you needed this for is public, please comment with a link to the website you created, if it is finished! thx